# Republic virus to destroy droids

Tags: star-wars, droids

Droids are computers with hardware and software, so my question is:

Why the Republic did not create a virus to destroy the memory of droids and thus win the war?

Comment: The fact that droids needed to be communicated with verbally, even just to each other, implies that they're not networked together at all. Infecting one with a virus is not going to necessarily do a whole lot of damage.

Comment: @phantom42 - A virus could plausibly be communicated via audio.

Comment: Plausibly? I know of no virus that has been communicated by audio in either the SW universe or our own.

Comment: @phantom42 [I beg to differ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking#2600_hertz)! As long as a computer system executes code based on external input there's the potential for a hack via that input, as long as it's carefully crafted.

Comment: An edit the source code of the machines in your creation could cause harm necessary, no?

Comment: Faking commands is not the same as inserting a virus.

Comment: @unwitting The Cap'n Crunch tone doesn't actually make the target system do anything it couldn't already do, they just didn't have any security built in.  To translate that to Star Wars, it's the same as walking up to a droid and saying "Hey, go kill yourself" - and because the droid programmers never thought of that scenario, the droid _would_ kill itself.

Comment: This question is infintately better than any story identification I have seen... voting to reopen

Comment: @Izkata not the same - you're talking about the situation in which a process has a set of defined commands it can accept, and someone walks up and tells it to do a stupid one.

I'm talking about someone walking up to it and saying something to it that fundamentally confuses something in the way it processes commands. Perhaps something that breaks the audio parser, idk - not being a real system the potential vulnerabilities aren't certain :)

My point is, dangerous input isn't usually dangerous because the machine knows how to do stupid and dangerous things to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a virus requires a flaw to exploit.  The republic would have to find a common flaw among all of the different droid versions then develop the virus that can be delivered to them en mass. The droids are AI so they could very well recognize the virus activity and eliminate it especially once the virus is recognized by the federation and distributes the signature.  This means that all the effort and expense of developing the virus is countered quickly potentially before it does any damage.

Droids can always be memory wiped and reset.  There are instances in the EU Where a slicer did rig droids to turn at specific times, or to take them over.  One of the tools they use are viruses.  But these are limited to a few droids usually.  There is a specific objective that they are trying to achieve rather than forcing the TU to rebuild its entire army.

And finally Palpatine was pulling the strings with the TU.  He did not want the war won early.  And once it was time to take them on, the emperor preferred to stamp them out completely with a military victory.  A hack would not have the same effect as having your forces completely annihilated by overwhelming force.  A big part of winning a war is the psychological factor.

Comment: Indeed, the republic could not spend unnecessarily efforts. I think it would take less effort to destroy the droids physically.